# Dynamic portion of a preference center based on data extension of child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cloudpage

Is it possible to pull in the columns based on an iterative basis?  Like using the nth value?

Use Case: want to unify 90% of a pref. center across all BUs (26) but allow for BUs to have their own preferences (some will have 5 publication options some will have up to 10..etc.
So, inherently, within the cloudpage, it would need to have a dynamic portion based on pref. center data extension at the BU level.

Comment: Edited to reflect a better base-level question.  Previous version was an end of the day thought dump that was pretty cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve your multi-business unit pref center model by using the SSJS WSProxy module. The `WSProxy.prototype.setClientId({ ... })` method allows you to interact with child business units by [specifying their ClientID/MID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_impersonate.htm).

Comment: You'll probably need to send the MID through the query string; the personalization string in the pref center's context will probably be the parent BU's, but I haven't tested.